# Filestream Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

Ive created this class to handle file io

```
public class FileStreamManager
{
    public FileStream fileStream;
    public StreamWriter streamWriter;
    public StreamReader streamReader;

    public bool CreateOrAppendFileForOutput(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {

            fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return false;
    }
    public void CloseCreateOrAppendFileForOutput()
    {
        try
        {
            fileStream.Dispose();
            streamWriter.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

and im using it in another class like

```
FileStreamManager fsmExcpLog = new FileStreamManager();
fsmExcpLog.CreateOrAppendFileForOutput(todaysTestDirPath + @"\ExceptionLog.txt");

FileStreamManager fsmOffersLog = new FileStreamManager();
fsmOffersLog.CreateOrAppendFileForOutput(todaysTestDirPath + @"\OffersLog.txt");

FileStreamManager fsmTestedAddLog = new FileStreamManager();
fsmExcpLog.CreateOrAppendFileForOutput(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AddressLogFilePath"].Trim());
```

but when i try to write using this

```
fsmTestedAddLog.streamWriter.WriteLine("Some Data");
```

it is giving me Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error.
i  looked at the abject stream variable while debugging they are null, 
My question is why are they getting null if i have not called CloseCreateOrAppendFileForOutput() method yet?

Comment: tried using `if (!File.Exists(fileName)) { throw new System.FileNotFoundException("File not Found"); }` inside the function `CreateOrAppendFileForOutput`?

Comment: no files are creating file i have checked the directory its just streams are getting null i dont know why

Comment: You should change your CloseCreateOrAppend... method name to "Dispose()" and have the class implement IDisposable.

Comment: ok i'll be doing that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the references are `null` because you set them in a `try` block. Maybe try creating a new object, and setting the files they reference within the `try` block?

Comment: i am doing that this `FileStreamManager fsmTestedAddLog = new FileStreamManager();` is in the try block but is in another class.

Comment: No, do something like `FileStreamManager fsmTestedAddLog = new FileStreamManager()` outside of the `try` block. Set the file it goes to inside the try block maybe?

Comment: Can please you explain why this was a problem?

Comment: It was a problem because the program doesn't think it is a reference because the `try` block CAN run, but won't if an exception is thrown. Since it only has a chance to run, it isn't necessarily an object, and your compiler wants to make sure it's an object :P

Comment: Probably a more technical explanation out there too.